# Best way to set a goal URL with a variable in GA?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a thank you page that I want as a goal, however, Shopify adds the ID of the order before the final part of the URL (i.e. [https://website.com/1234/[variable](https://website.com/1234/%5Bvariable) ID]/thank_you)

I also need to track how they got to this thank you page to make sure they use a specific landing page.

If I set the following as the destination and funnel, is that the best way? Any help is appreciated

Destination https://[website URL]/40470315170/checkouts/./thank_you.    Regular Expression

First Page  https://[website URL]/a/offers/f/18603/0/selector           Required

Second Page https://[website URL]/a/offers/f/18603/3/selector

Third Page  https://[website URL]/40470315170/checkouts/.*

Answer (score 0):

Destination and Third Page step turn out the same, so either remove the third step or make it more restrictive.